# Adding Image to FixedPage in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, image, fixedpage

I want to be able to print images with other UIElements. I have a FixedPage instance and trying to add image like so

```
// Basic printing stuff
var printDialog = new PrintDialog();
var fixedDocument = new FixedDocument();
fixedDocument.DocumentPaginator.PageSize = new Size(printDialog.PrintableAreaWidth, printDialog.PrintableAreaHeight);

FixedPage page = new FixedPage();
page.Width = fixedDocument.DocumentPaginator.PageSize.Width;
page.Height = fixedDocument.DocumentPaginator.PageSize.Height;

Image img = new Image();

// PrintIt my project's name, Img folder
var uriImageSource = new Uri(@"/PrintIt;component/Img/Stuff.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
img.Source = new BitmapImage(uriImageSource);
img.Width = 100;
img.Height = 100;

page.Children.Add(img);

PageContent pageContent = new PageContent();
((IAddChild)pageContent).AddChild(page);

fixedDocument.Pages.Add(pageContent);

// Print me an image please!
_printDialog.PrintDocument(fixedDocument.DocumentPaginator, "Print");
```

It gives me a blank paper. I'm wondering why, because other UIElements (such as TextBox, Grid, Rect) appear with no problems. What am I missing?

Thanks!

PS OK, I've found another solution. I don't know why but with that Uri a picture loads properly

```
var uri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Img/Stuff.png");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be more clear on my Code

```
var bitImage = new BitmapImage();
bitImage.BeginInit();
bitImage.StreamSource = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
bitImage.DecodePixelWidth = 250;
bitImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
bitImage.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreColorProfile;
bitImage.EndInit();
bitImage.StreamSource.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
bitImage.Freeze();

var tempImage = new Image {Source = bitImage};
var imageObject = new ImageObject(tempImage, fileName);
bitImage.StreamSource.Dispose();
page.Children.Add(imageObject);
```

Comment: Just a note: when running this code on a "big" (= lot of pages) FixedDocument, OutOfMemoryExceptions are not thrown by the code. They are simply ignored and the images are not displayed. The behavior is different whit this code: BitmapFrame bitImage = BitmapFrame.Create(new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read), BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);

Comment: This code produces the error: "The type or namespace name 'ImageObject' could not be found"

Answer (score 0):

First i would like to suggest that, see below.

```
Set the sourceStream of the Image for BitMap
    bitImage.StreamSource = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
```

Then freeze the BitMap Image, or it ll not be in the instance as render able image.

```
bitImage.StreamSource.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
bitImage.Freeze();
```

This should work, if not i personally think it is a bad idea to directly work with BitMaps, i use Bitmap to create image form file then copy it to the type Image(system.drawing iguess), something like below

```
var tempImage = new Image {Source = bitImage};
var imageObject = new ImageObject(tempImage, fileName);
bitImage.StreamSource.Dispose();
```

this tempImage can be added to ur page as regular UIElement.
Hope it helps.