# What is the correct way to print images using WPF DocumentPaginator

Tags: c#, wpf, image, documentpaginator

Here is my code that is in a class extending `DocumentPaginator`

```
    public override DocumentPage GetPage(int pageNumber)
    {
        BitmapImage source = new BitmapImage();
        using (Stream stream = new FileStream(GetPagePath(pageNumber), FileMode.Open))
        {
            source.BeginInit();
            source.StreamSource = stream;
            source.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            source.EndInit();
        }

        var image = new Image { Source = source };

        Rect contentBox = new Rect(PageSize);

        return new DocumentPage(image, PageSize, contentBox, contentBox);
    }
```

However when I actually run this code, it doesn't seem to load my image and merely prints blank pages.

What is the correct way to load my image and attach it to a `DocumentPage` object?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding Image to FixedPage in WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11853096/adding-image-to-fixedpage-in-wpf)

Comment: I had seen that post... a `FixedPage` is not the same thing as a `DocumentPage`.

Comment: Have you tried the code from that answer for creating the `BitmapImage` instance?

Comment: Yes.  It had no effect on the output.

Comment: What does the `GetPagePath` method do?

Comment: Returns a string with the full path of a file.

Comment: What kind of file is it?

Comment: instead of assigning `StreamSource`, have you tried setting `UriSource` to the path of the image, like `source.UriSource = new Uri(GetPagePath(pageNumber));` ?  This is how we're doing it in our in-house applications.

Comment: @JoshuaShearer If you want to be sure that the BitmapImage is loaded immediately, you have to set the StreamSource property and also set the BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad flag, as OP does. There's nothing wrong with that part of the code.

Comment: @Clemens Thanks for the info.  One less place to look for issues, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

You must do the layout of the Image control by calling its `Measure()` and `Arrange()` methods:

```
var image = new Image { Source = source };
var size = new Size(source.PixelWidth, source.PixelHeight);
image.Measure(size);
image.Arrange(new Rect(size));
```